# Nesting java8 streams to get a collection by Predicate

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to get a collection of Objects, from a Collection using streams in Java8  based on some predicate

Here is what I have tried, but there is some syntax error in this.:

```
Collection<object> objectCollectionNew = objectCollection.stream().filter(o -> objectCollection.stream().filter( x- > x.isTrue == o.isTrue));
```

So basically I want to get a collection of objects out of the `objectCollection` based on my Predicate. Also I am unsure about how to collect this into my `Collection<object>`.

`.collect(Collectors.to ?? )`

Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to compare each object in the collection with every other object in the same collection and based on my predicate output that collection.

Comment: "*but there is some syntax error in this*" can you post this error so people with similar problem would be able to find your question and its answers?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but if you want to find all elements of your collection whose `isTrue` is equal to `isTrue` of some other element of the collection, you would do it like this:

```
objectColelction.stream()
    .filter(o -> objectColelction.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.isTrue == o.isTrue))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to use a `flatMap` :

```
Collection<object> objectCollectionNew = objectCollection.stream()
                                              .flatMap(o -> objectCollection.stream().filter(x -> x.isTrue == o.isTrue))
                                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: this still gives me the syntax error that I was getting earlier : `Syntax error on token ")", ElidedSemicolonAndRightBrace expected`

Comment: @RahulRaina I get no syntax error, try copying my example directly.

Comment: I removed the parenthesis after `isTrue` as I tought it was a method call. If it's a variable and you simply replaced the name ignoring these parenthesis then this may be why you get the syntax error.

Comment: I get the same errror on a similar piece of code. Looks like a bug in Eclipse

Comment: The ElidedSemicolonAndRightBrace error occurs when you have more closing parenthesis ")" than opening ones "(".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which looks like an error in the Eclipse syntax parser. I solved it by adding parenthesis

```
Collection<object> objectCollectionNew = objectCollection.stream()
.filter( x -> {return x.isTrue == o.isTrue;} )
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Just answering on the syntax aspect, not how to best solve your filtering itself.

Comment: What is `o` variable in your example?